# Button has no text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('#enable_disable_btn').unbind('click');
    if ('{{$userStatus()}}' == 'Active') {
        $('#enable_disable_btn').html("Disable User");
        $('#enable_disable_btn').click(DisableUser);
    } else {
        $('#enable_disable_btn').html("Enable User");
        $('#enable_disable_btn').click(EnableUser);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="enable_disable_btn"></a>
```

The button appears blank, no text. I wonder whats wrong here.

Comment: check you console for any erros

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: This: http://jsfiddle.net/cbUzh/1 is working.

Comment: You soure that's the same code you posted here? Maybe typo and you want class instead of id? Or mybe there is more than one element with this id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a

```
<input type="submit">
```

or similar, you'll have to use

```
$(...).val("Enable User");
```

as it's the `value` attribute that is displayed on the button.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a input type="button" or "submit" then you must use `jQuery('#enable_disable_btn').val('Disable user')`

Comment: That wouldn't work. Should be `jQuery('#enable_disable_btn').val('Disable user')`